# Apache Jena all release notes so far

Tags: release, jena

I am trying to find all the release notes of each of the versions released so far for Apache Jena. Where can I find it?

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?version=12340535&styleName=&projectId=12311220&Create=Create&atl_token=A5KQ-2QAV-T4JA-FDED%7C29a7f7bf1801473200dd1625efdeb545db31a640%7Clout Press "Configure Release Notes" and select a version.

Comment: Why not ask this on the project mailing lists? http://jena.apache.org/help_and_support/

Comment: @StanislavKralinPlease add your comment as an answer so that I can accept it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASF JIRA allows to create release notes for hosted projects.
On  the [Configure Release Notes](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?version=-3&styleName=Html&projectId=12311220) page, select a version and press the "Create" button.

If you have an ASF JIRA account, you can visit the [Releases](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/JENA?selectedItem=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:release-page&status=released) page directly.

For future release notes, you could also subscribe to [users@jena.apache.org](https://lists.apache.org/list.html?users@jena.apache.org).